# Merge 2 xslt files

Tags: xml, xslt

I have two xslt files (let them be file1 and file2). They have some identical parts and also some parts which are different (for example in both of them there is template 'A' with different realization). And depending on the situatuion I use one of this files. 
Is there a way to merge these two files into one (which will store two variants of realization if it is different, one if the same) and then choose if I want to work with this file like with file1 or file2? 
How can I perform such merge(any libraries/tools/etc)? And how can I tell the result file I want him to be like file1 or file2?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds as if you simply want to write two main stylesheets importing your files doing e.g.

```
<xsl:import href="file1.xslt"/>
<xsl:import href="file2.xslt"/>
```

in one and

```
<xsl:import href="file2.xslt"/>
<xsl:import href="file1.xslt"/>
```

in the other. The depending on your needs you apply one of the main stylesheets, in the first example the definitions in `file2.xslt` will have precedence over those in `file1.xslt`, in the second example it is the other way around.. See https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#import (respectively https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#import for XSLT 2.0 and an explanation a bit more detailed) to find details on import precedence.

Comment: Thanks, but it`s not actually what I wanted. I want to combine the code of two files in one file. I mentioned that some parts are the same, so if I want to edit them I have to do it in 2 files which may lead to errors due inattentiveness.

Comment: So you want to do that step only once and then no longer use the files you have merged but only use the merged file?

Comment: Then you could just copy-and-paste variable definitions and templates of one file into the other one, and try to apply the transformation: the XSLT processor should warn you about _ambiguous matches_ when different templates could be applied to the same active node (at least, Saxon does this).